# Airflow DockerOperator unable to mount tmp directory correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to run a simple python script within a docker run command scheduled with Airflow.

I have followed the instructions here [Airflow init](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html).

My `.env` file:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=1000
AIRFLOW_GID=0
```

And the `docker-compose.yaml` is based on the default one [docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/docker-compose.yaml). I had to add `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` as an additional volume to run docker inside of docker.

My dag is configured as followed:

```py
""" this is an example dag """
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from docker.types import Mount

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['info@foo.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 10,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
with DAG(
    'msg_europe_etl',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Process MSG_EUROPE ETL',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=15),
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    tags=['satellite_data'],
) as dag:

    download_and_store = DockerOperator(
        task_id='download_and_store',
        image='satellite_image:latest',
        auto_remove=True,
        api_version='1.41',
        mounts=[Mount(source='/home/archive_1/archive/satellite_data',
                      target='/app/data'),
                Mount(source='/home/dlassahn/projects/forecast-system/meteoIntelligence-satellite',
                      target='/app')],
        command="python3 src/scripts.py download_satellite_images "
                     "{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(hours=4)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') }} "
                     "'msg_europe' ",
    )

    download_and_store
```

The Airflow log:

```py
[2021-08-03 17:23:58,691] {docker.py:231} INFO - Starting docker container from image satellite_image:latest
[2021-08-03 17:23:58,702] {taskinstance.py:1501} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1157, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1331, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1361, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 319, in execute
    return self._run_image()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 258, in _run_image
    tty=self.tty,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 430, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 441, in create_container_from_config
    return self._result(res, True)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 274, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/airflowtmp037k87u6")
```

Trying to set `mount_tmp_dir=False` yield to an Dag ImportError because of unknown Keyword Argument `mount_tmp_dir`.  (this might be an issue for the Documentation)

Nevertheless I do not know how to configure the tmp directory correctly.

My Airflow Version: 2.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in Docker Provider 2.0.0 which prevented Docker Operator to run with Docker-In-Docker solution.

You need to upgrade to the latest Docker Provider 2.1.0
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/index.html#id1

You can do it by extending the image as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-the-image with - for example - this docker file:

```
FROM apache/airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-docker==2.1.0
```

The operator will work out-of-the-box in this case with "fallback" mode (and Warning message), but you can also disable the mount that causes the problem. More explanation from the https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html

> By default, a temporary directory is created on the host and mounted
> into a container to allow storing files that together exceed the
> default disk size of 10GB in a container. In this case The path to the
> mounted directory can be accessed via the environment variable
> AIRFLOW_TMP_DIR.
>
> If the volume cannot be mounted, warning is printed and an attempt is
> made to execute the docker command without the temporary folder
> mounted. This is to make it works by default with remote docker engine
> or when you run docker-in-docker solution and temporary directory is
> not shared with the docker engine. Warning is printed in logs in this
> case.
>
> If you know you run DockerOperator with remote engine or via
> docker-in-docker you should set mount_tmp_dir parameter to False. In
> this case, you can still use mounts parameter to mount already
> existing named volumes in your Docker Engine to achieve similar
> capability where you can store files exceeding default disk size of
> the container,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and all "recommended" ways of solving the issue here and setting up mount_dir params as descripted [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html) just lead to other errors. The one solution that helped me was wrapping the invocated by docker code with the VPN (actually this hack was taken from another docker-powered DAG that used VPN and worked well).

So the final solution looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

connect_to_vpn.sh &
sleep 10
python3 my_func.py
sleep 10
stop_vpn.sh
wait -n
exit $?
```

To connect to VPN I used openconnect. The took can be installed with apt install and supports anyconnect protocol (it was my crucial requirement).